# What does rpm -H do?

Tags: linux, rpm

I came across someone's RPM command that wrote:

```
rpm -ivH ....
```

and then noticed that option `-H` is not documented anywhere.

Command `rpm -H` no longer works with newer version of rpm, however it runs successfully under rpm version 4.8, produces no output and then exits.

So what is the command `rpm -H` used to do?

System is a Scientific Linux 6.1:

```
$ rpm --version
RPM version 4.8.0
$ rpm -H
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Are you sure it's capital 'H'?

Comment: @UVV Affirmative.

Comment: Probably a typo, should have been `h`.

Comment: @Mat - doesn't appear to be a typo, see my A, it's a real switch that was confirmed to exist in 4.8 at least.

Comment: @slm: does that option make any sense in `-i` mode?

Comment: @Mat - good point, I never saw it used in that context, so you're probably right 8-). He shows that sample but then asks about `-H` by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Are we sure it isn't a typo?

Are you sure that worked under 4.8? I just tried it in `4.3.2`.

```
$ rpm --version
RPM version 4.3.2

$ rpm -H
-H: unknown option
```

#### 2. Switch is confirmed!

This seems to be limited to just version 4.8 only.

```
$ rpm -H
$ 

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

#### 3. Evidence of its existence

I did find this thread on rpm5.org, titled: [Re: parsing hdlists with rpmgi?](http://rpm5.org/community/rpm-devel/4398.html) which shows the `-H` switch in action.

```
$ rpm -qH
    error: rpmpkgRead: Header: Header V3 DSA signature: UNKNOWN, key ID 26752624
    [jbj@localhost tmp]$ sudo rpm --import 0x26752624
    [jbj@localhost tmp]$ rpm -qH
    error: rpmpkgRead: Header: Header V3 DSA signature: UNKNOWN, key ID 26752624
```

and here:

```
$ rpm -qH -vv --nosignature
D: pool fd: created size 384 limit -1 flags 0
D: pool lua:    created size 56 limit -1 flags 0
D: pool ts: created size 1192 limit -1 flags 0
D: pool gi: created size 160 limit -1 flags 0
D: pool dig:    created size 400 limit -1 flags 0
D: pool ctx:    created size 104 limit -1 flags 0
D: pool h:  created size 352 limit -1 flags 0
lib64rpm1-4.8.1-1mnb2.x86_64
x11-driver-video-ati-6.13.99-0.20101119.1mdv2011.0.x86_64
```

#### 4. Smoking gun...Git commit logs!

This would appear to be the smoking gun. This shows a discussion in removing this feature. It's the [git commit log](http://rpm.org/gitweb?p=rpm.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=367c0d7014b769a5c12f83b525dddb0a7c76beef).

```
From: Panu Matilainen <pmatilai@redhat.com>
Date: Fri, 19 Mar 2010 14:54:00 +0000 (+0200)
Subject: Eliminate hysterical --hdlist query option and everything implementing it
X-Git-Tag: rpm-4.9.0-beta1~839
X-Git-Url: http://rpm.org/gitweb?p=rpm.git;a=commitdiff_plain;h=367c0d7014b769a5c12f83b525dddb0a7c76beef

...
Eliminate hysterical --hdlist query option and everything implementing it
- This hidden gem used "system hdlist", ie "/usr/share/comps/%{_arch}/hdlist
  as the source for queries. Such "system hdlist" hasn't existed anywhere
  since RHL 9/FC 1 times...
```

In that same thread is this code snippet which shows the switch being removed.

```
- { "hdlist", 'H', POPT_ARGFLAG_DOC_HIDDEN, 0, POPT_HDLIST,
-   N_("query/verify package(s) from system HDLIST"), "HDLIST" },
-
```

So the switch is synonymous with `--hdlist`.

#### References

- [5.3 Generating a new hdlist file](http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/RedHat-CD-HOWTO-5.html)

Comment: I mean rpm 4.8 specifically

Comment: @HowardGuo - thanks for the Q. I learned something new from it as well. 8-)